# Why is there no compiler warning when I add a try finally to a method missing a return type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings

This question is pretty academic but just now I noticed that XCode was not complaining about the following code.

```
+ (double) someMethod {
   @try {

   }
   @ catch (NSException *exception){}
}
```

There is no return value but the compiler is not giving an error.
It compiles and runs on a device.

If I try print it with `NSLog(@"Value is %f", [AppDelegate someMethod]);`
It prints Value is 0.000000

What's going on here? Probably a bug in the compiler but it does appear to be returning something, what going on behind the scenes with the try catch so that its returning a value, anyone any ideas?

Comment: It's almost certainly a bug in the compiler.

Comment: what does it return ?